# How to calculate shift and rolling sum over missing dates without adding them to data frame in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, date, time-series, missing-data

I have a data set with dates, customers and income:

```
    Date    CustomerIncome
0   1/1/2018    A   53
1   2/1/2018    A   36
2   3/1/2018    A   53
3   5/1/2018    A   89
4   6/1/2018    A   84
5   8/1/2018    A   84
6   9/1/2018    A   54
7   10/1/2018   A   19
8   11/1/2018   A   44
9   12/1/2018   A   80
10  1/1/2018    B   24
11  2/1/2018    B   100
12  9/1/2018    B   40
13  10/1/2018   B   47
14  12/1/2018   B   10
15  2/1/2019    B   5
```

For both customers there are missing dates as they purchased nothing at some months.
I want to add per each customer what was the income of last month and also the rolling sum of income for the last year.
Meaning, if there's a missing month, I'll see '0' at the shift(1) column of the following month that has income. And I'll see rolling sum of 12 months even if there weren't 12 observations.

This is the expected result:

```
  Date  CustomerIncome  S(1)R(12)
0   1/1/2018    A   53  0   53
1   2/1/2018    A   36  53  89
2   3/1/2018    A   53  36  142
3   5/1/2018    A   89  0   231
4   6/1/2018    A   84  89  315
5   8/1/2018    A   84  0   399
6   9/1/2018    A   54  84  453
7   10/1/2018   A   19  54  472
8   11/1/2018   A   44  19  516
9   12/1/2018   A   80  44  596
10  1/1/2018    B   24  0   24
11  2/1/2018    B   100 24  124
12  9/1/2018    B   40  0   164
13  10/1/2018   B   47  40  211
14  12/1/2018   B   10  0   221
15  2/1/2019    B   5   0   102
```

So far, I've added the rows with missing dates with stack and unstack, but with multiple dates  and customers, it explodes the data to millions of rows, crashing kernel with most rows are 0's.

Comment: Rolling on `Month` is a pain...

Comment: @Alex How come customer A starts at 53 for rolling 12, but Customer B starts at zero? My answer will reflect different output. Kindly see if that is desired. Also, is it okay to have more rows? Can you try this on your dataframe?

Comment: You're right, fixed. As I've mentioned, I can add a row for each missing month with income 0, but it will explode the data in a way that makes computation very slow, if successful at all (I tried it).

Comment: @Alex I think some of your output in the second group may be incorrect. Kindly check against my output.

Comment: Output edited in R(12) for customer B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `.shift` but have logic that if the gap is > 31 days, then make `(S1)` = `0`
2. The rolling 12 calculation requires figuring out the "Rolling Date" and doing some complicated list comprehension to decide whether or not to return a value. Then, take a sum of each list per row.

---

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['S(1)'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Income'].transform('shift').fillna(0)
s = (df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift())/np.timedelta64(1, '31D') <= 1
df['S(1)'] = df['S(1)'].where(s,0).astype(int)
df['Rolling Date'] = (df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta('1Y'))
df['R(12)'] = df.apply(lambda d: sum([z for x,y,z in 
                                      zip(df['Customer'], df['Date'], df['Income']) 
                                      if y > d['Rolling Date'] 
                                      if y <= d['Date'] 
                                      if x == d['Customer']]), axis=1)
df = df.drop('Rolling Date', axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
          Date Customer  Income  S(1)  R(12)
0   2018-01-01        A      53     0     53
1   2018-02-01        A      36    53     89
2   2018-03-01        A      53    36    142
3   2018-05-01        A      89     0    231
4   2018-06-01        A      84    89    315
5   2018-08-01        A      84     0    399
6   2018-09-01        A      54    84    453
7   2018-10-01        A      19    54    472
8   2018-11-01        A      44    19    516
9   2018-12-01        A      80    44    596
10  2018-01-01        B      24     0     24
11  2018-02-01        B     100    24    124
12  2018-09-01        B      40     0    164
13  2018-10-01        B      47    40    211
14  2018-12-01        B      10     0    221
15  2019-02-01        B       5     0    102
```

Comment: As I've mentioned, I wan to avoid adding multiple rows with 0's as this explodes my actual data to many millions of rows making further computation slow or not succeeding at all for various features such as I mentioned (I tried it at first).

Comment: @Alex gotchya, I have calculated `(S1)` in a performant way (See updated answer). Let's see what I can do with rolling.

Comment: @Alex can you try this on a subset on your dataframe or a subset of it? This doesn't add any additional rows, but the rolling calculation might be intensive.

Comment: It's great thank you! Can your approach be adjusted for cases where the missing 0s influence the calculation? For example running coefficient of linear regression for the past 12 months - the 0s should be included as they influence the coef..?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The list comprehension can contain more conditional if logic with the x, y or z variables.

Comment: Also, @Alex kindly accept the solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer as well as upvote if helpful. Thank you,  I appreciate it!

Comment: @Alex just following up I believe you upvoted but you may have missed clicking the "Accept" checkmark next to my solution. Thank you and this was a really cool problem!